# Why does QTextEdit have sometimes document height 0?

Tags: qt

For a QTextEdit* `te` I have noticed that sometimes `te->document()->size()` returns (0,0) and sometimes it returns the actual size. In both cases, `te->toPlainText()` returns non-empty text.

What can be done for it to return the size?
Is there some refresh method so the document will definitely return the size after it?

Comment: Do you initialize *te with a value?

Comment: Since this may be a bug, we'd need to know the exact Qt version and the platform you run on (32 vs 64 bit, OS, compiler, self-compiled vs. pre-built). We also need a self-contained test case - make sure it's single file, it should be hopefully 1-2 dozen lines.

Comment: Try to call `QApplication::processEvents()` before checking size. Note that invisible documents still may not return correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `QApplication::processEvents()` before checking size. It will cause processing of all pending Qt events, so after this call all sizes will be updated. Note that invisible documents still may not return correct size.

Answer (score -1):

Calculating layout of text is heavy operation, especially when text is long, so this have to be delayed as possible. I'm pretty sure that you get this zero size somewhere in construction time.

How you can overcome this problem?
Best approach is lazy initialization. Do not perform calculation until some value is relay needed (it you do this properly you will never get zero size).
Other approach is to enforce calculation of document layout. You can do it by calling `setTextWidth()`, `setPageSize()` or `idealWidth()` depending on context of your task.

`idealWidth()` is perfect if you do not wrap lines and don't have page size.